# How to perform a regression for a multi-function?

Tags: regression, function

How would one perform a regression analysis with a multi-function? That is, where a single X-value can correspond to a number of Y-values? Here is an example:
[image]

Note that in this example, it is not enough to simply add a regression model with less bias or more complex features. The issue is that is the response variable is not truly a function of the independent variable.

What are the generally accepted approaches for regressions in such situations?

Answer (score 1):

This problem is generally treated with Clusterwise Linear Regression (CLR) techniques where, as the name suggests, the data is segmented into clusters and linear regression is performed on each cluster, separately. There are quite some literature on it but you might want to check [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1804.10742.pdf).

Comment: how would one know in such a case which cluster the out of sample data comes from? i.e. which of the sub-models to use for out of sample.

Comment: CLR models attempt to partition the data into clusters such that the clusterwise linear regression errors are minimized. So, once cluster characteristics are learnt, you can assign out of sample to the the cluster it is likely to belong and summon the model specific to it.

Comment: @Ozan. Thanks for the reference!

Answer (score 0):

It seems from the data that a single linear model won't do the trick.

Are you pooling observations from multiple datasets together? If so try to separate out the datasets.

It could be a situation where the relationship is:

```
if observation_from(setA): linear_relationship
else no relationship
```

For example, if you're modeling ml_fluid_consumed vs blood_sugar and you get into a similar situation; you might find out that actually there are multiple variables; ml_fluid_consumed_water, ml_fluid_consumed_soda etc. Once you have that, then modeling is simplified.

Comment: A simple multiple regression model might do the trick in the case you propose: model `y ~ x + setAmembership + x:setAmembership `, where the ":" represents an interaction term. That's assuming that all of the lower branch were in one or the other of the sets and that the sets were pre-defined rather than estimated from the data.

Comment: agreed, this would work as well. I guess setAmembership is crucial to know.